# Bootstrap 3 IE Grid Compatibillity

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have created a bootstrap 3 website and it looks great except in some versions of Internet Explorer the grids overlap each other. The url is awseattle.com the html code looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="AW Seattle provides luxury transportation services in the Greater Seattle-Tacoma &amp; Airport area. We operate a full fleet of vehicles 24 hours a day, 7 days a week. (206) 412-9353">
    <meta name="author" content="awseattle.com">
    <meta name="keywords" content="seattle limo, limousine service, airport limo, cruise transfers, limo service" />
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, NOFOLLOW">
    <title>AW Seattle</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/grayscale.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

     <script src="js/DateTimePicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Respond.js proxy on external server -->
    <link href="http://externalcdn.com/respond-proxy.html" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy" />


</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
                      <span class="light">AW</span> Seattle
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#fleet">Fleet</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#rates">Rates</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#reservations">Reservations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Intro Header -->
    <header class="intro">
        <div class="intro-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <div>
                        <br><br><br><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <!---- Carosel --->
                        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                          <!-- Indicators -->
                          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                          </ol>

                          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="item active">
                              <img width='500' height='250' src="img/towncar.jpg" alt="AW Seattle Town Car">
                              <div class="carousel-caption">

                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                              <img width='500' height='250' src="img/seattle.jpg" alt="AW Seattle">
                              <div class="carousel-caption">

                              </div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="item">
                              <img width='500' height='250' src="img/chauffeur.jpg" alt="chauffeur">
                              <div class="carousel-caption">

                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <!-- Controls -->
                          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                          </a>
                          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                          </a>
                        </div>
                        <!---- End Carosel --->
                                <br>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                  <div class="panel-body">
                                    <font color='gray'> We take pride in making every trip a memorable experience. We have been rated one of the best towncar and limousine companies in the Greater Puget Sound area. We have been based in the Seattle Metropolitan area since 2000 and have built our business one customer at a time.
<Br><br>
Our service and prices set us apart from other companies, which makes our company highly competitive. Our experienced drivers are knowledgeable about city streets and locations statewide, are courteous, personable, and confident. Our town cars are meticulously clean and well-maintained. You can relax in luxury as you are safely taken to your desired destination.</font>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <br>
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                      <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3 class="panel-title">Account Log In</h3>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="panel-body">
                                         <form method="post" action="index.php">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                          <input name="user" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">
                                        </div><Br>
                                         <div class="input-group">
                                          <input name="pass" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                          <Br>
                                              <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in">
                                        </form> 
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                     <div class="panel panel-default">
                                      <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3 class="panel-title">Proud Transporter of</h3>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="panel-body">
                                        <img src="img/microsoft.png" alt="microsoft" style="width:150px;height:40px"><Br>
                                          <img src="img/amazon.jpg" alt="amazon" style="width:150px;height:40px"><Br>
                                          <img src="img/boeing.jpg" alt="boeing" style="width:150px;height:40px"><Br>
                                          <img src="img/passportunlimited.jpg" alt="passport unlimited" style="width:150px;height:40px"><Br>
                                          <img src="img/facebook.png" alt="facebook" style="width:150px;height:40px"><Br>
                                        <img src="img/eddiebauer.jpg" alt="eddie bauer" style="width:150px;height:40px">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                      <div class="panel-body">
                                        <a href='http://www.heathmanhotel.com/'>Hotel Reservations</a><br>
                                        <a href='http://www.weather.com/weather/today/Seattle+WA+USWA0395?from=search_city'>Weather</a><br>
                                        <a href='http://www.citysearch.com/guide/seattle-wa-metro'>Around Seattle</a><br>

                                      </div>
                                    </div>

                    </div>







                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <br><br><br><br>



                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>


    <section id="fleet" class="container content-section text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h2>OUR FLEET</h2>
               <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/Fleet_TownCar.jpg" width="450" height="150" class="img-responsive" alt="Town Car">
            Luxury Signature and L model Town Cars up to 4 passengers 
        </a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/Fleet_WhiteLimo.jpg" width="450" height="150" class="img-responsive" alt="White Limo">
            Seats 8-10 passengers, Tinted windows, Privacy divider 
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/Fleet_Suv.jpg" width="450" height="150" class="img-responsive" alt="SUV">
            Seats up to 7 passengers, Climate controlled, Ample luggage room
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/Fleet_Van.jpg" width="450" height="150" class="img-responsive" alt="Van">
            Seats up to 14 passengers, Ample leg room, Privacy dividers         
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/Fleet_SuvLimo.jpg" width="450" height="150" class="img-responsive" alt="SUV Limo">
            Seats up to 14 people, Rear luggage space, Sound system 
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/Fleet_mkt.jpg" width="450" height="150" class="img-responsive" alt="MKT">
            Seats 7 comfortably with lots of leg room and style in a Lincon MKT.
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/Fleet_partybus.jpg" width="450" height="150" class="img-responsive" alt="Party Bus">
            <br>Seats up to 16 people
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/Fleet_Bus.jpg" width="450" height="150" class="img-responsive" alt="Bus">
            Luxury Buses, Seats 39-54 people, Ample luggage room, TV/DVD 
        </a>
    </div>


  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section id="services" class="content-section text-center">
        <div class="download-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <h2>Services</h2>

                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                  <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">WEDDINGS, PROMS AND SPECIAL OCCASIONS</h3>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="panel-body">
                                      <div class="col-md-4">
                                          <img src="img/wedding.jpg" alt="wedding" height="100%" width="100%">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-md-8">
                                          <font size="2" color="gray">On your special day everything must be perfect! Planning for a special occasion is very stressful, so let us take some of your stress away. Arrive and leave in style in one of our beautiful limousines. We guarantee that you will make it to all of your planned destinations on time and worry free. Let us help you make your special day the one to remember for years to come.</font>
                                      </div>

                                  </div>
                                </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                  <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">CITY TOURS</h3>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="panel-body">
                                       <div class="col-md-4">
                                          <img src="img/city.jpg" alt="city" height="100%" width="100%">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-md-8">
                                          <font size="2" color="gray">Whether you are new to the Seattle area or have lived here your entire life and need to be reacquainted with our fair city, allow AW Seattle Towncar Service show you the splendor of the Pacific Northwest. Our drivers are well familiar with the area and will be able to provide a memorable experience for you and your family.</font>
                                      </div>

                                  </div>
                                </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                  <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">CORPORATE</h3>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="panel-body">
                                      <div class="col-md-4">
                                          <img src="img/corprate.jpg" alt="corprate" height="100%" width="100%">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-md-8">
                                          <font size="2" color="gray">Take the worry out of your busy work day! Allow reliable and dependable drivers of AW Seattle Towncar Service take you to and from your business meetings in style and luxury. You will enjoy a smooth relaxing ride and arrive at your business meeting in a timely matter.</font>
                                      </div>

                                  </div>
                                </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                  <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">GROUND TRANSPORTATION SERVICE</h3>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="panel-body">
                                      <div class="col-md-4">
                                          <img src="img/ground.jpg" alt="ground" height="100%" width="100%">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-md-8">
                                          <font size="2" color="gray">We began our business with ground transportation service and to this day continue to offer luxury and comfortable rides to and from the SeaTac Airport. Let go of all of your worries about traffic on the roads, rental cars or finding reliable parking for your vehicle. Allow our drivers to take you to the airport or home in style and on time.</font>
                                      </div>

                                  </div>
                                </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                  <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">Service Agreement</h3>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="panel-body" align="left">

                                      <div class="col-md-12">
                                          <font size="2" color="gray">
                                              <ul>

        <li>All round-trip reservations to be booked with return itinerary at the time of the initial booking </li>
        <li>Reservations should include cell phone contact information ONLY; Home and office telephone numbers are irrelevant for coordinating pickups </li>
        <li>When exiting baggage claim client to call dispatch @ 206 412-9353 to inform from which exit door they can be met </li>
        <li>Car seats for children are not provided but can be accommodated for drop-off at Sea-Tac and return will have the seats available for return to home at "one time charge" of $10.00 per seat </li>
        <li>Trips between Midnight and 4:00 AM will result in a $10.00 surcharge </li>
        <li>Stops en-route will result in an additional $10.00 service fee </li>
        <li>Credit card information is kept on file ONLY if requested by the customer, otherwise client needs to present the card for payment to the driver each time </li>
        <li>$10 charge to have a driver meet inside with sign at baggage claim </li>
        <li>Reservations must be cancelled within 2 hours of pickup to avoid penalties </li>
        <li>No-show reservations will result in full charge for the trip </li>
        <li>Smoking is NOT permitted </li>
        <li>Drinking alcohol is permitted; driver discretionary limits </li>

                                              </ul>

</font>
                                      </div>

                                  </div>
                                </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

     <section id="rates" class="container content-section text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h2>Rates</h2>
                <br><br>
                <table width='100%' align='center'>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='right'><font size='5'>Calculate your rate:</font></td>
                        <td width="5%"></td>
                        <td align='left'><div class="dropdown">
                              <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Event Type
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                              </button>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" onclick='$("#toFromModal").modal({keyboard: false})'>Transportation to or from Sea Tac Airport</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" onclick='$("#cityTourModal").modal({keyboard: false})'>City Tour</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" onclick='$("#specialEventsModal").modal({keyboard: false})'>Special Occasion</a></li>


                              </ul>
                            </div></td>

                </table>

<div class="modal fade" id="cityTourModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><font color='black'>City Tours</font></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"><font color='gray'>
        Your Rate is estimated at: $65 / hour for town cars<br><br>
          Rates vary based on events, vehicles, and people. Rates are subject to change.
      </font></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="specialEventsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><font color='black'>Special Events</font></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <font color='gray'>
        Your Rate is estimated at: $65 / hour for town cars<br><br>
          Rates vary based on events, vehicles, and people. Rates are subject to change.
      </font>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="toFromModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><font color='black'>To or From Sea Tac Airport</font></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <select id='zip' name='zip' onchange="document.getElementById('ratediv').firstChild.nodeValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
            <option value=''>Select A Pick Up / Drop Off Area</option>
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ziprates GROUP BY city";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value='$".$row['ratelow']." - $". $row['ratehigh']."'>". $row['city']."</option>";
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?> 






        </select>
          <br><br>

          <font color='gray'>
            Your Rate is estimated at:<br> 
          <div id='ratediv'>

          </div><br><br>
              Rates are for one way travel. Round trip is double.<br>
              Lowest price is based on closest location to Sea Tac Airport<br>
          Rates vary based on events, vehicles, and people. Rates are subject to change.
        </font>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>There is $65.00 per hour charge for city tours and any other occasion. <br>Downtown Seattle to/from Sea-Tac Airport flat rate of $55.00. <br><br><br><br>All rates may be subject to change. 
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

     <section id="reservations" class="content-section text-center">
        <div class="download-section">
            <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <h2>Reservations</h2>
                        <br>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Select a event type to make a reservation:</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="panel-body"   align="center">

                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style='width: 310px;' onclick='$("#tofromModal").modal({keyboard: false})'><span class="network-name">TO / From Sea TAc Airport</span></a>
                          <br>
                          <a href='customroute.php' class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style='width: 310px;'><span class="network-name">Custom Route</span></a>
                      </div>
                    </div>





                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


<div class="modal fade" id="tofromModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" align="center">

      <div class="modal-body">
       <a href='toseatac.php' class="btn btn-default btn-md" style='width: 310px;'><span class="network-name">To Sea Tac Airport</span></a><br>
       <a href='fromseatac.php' class="btn btn-default btn-md" style='width: 310px;'><span class="network-name">From Sea Tac Airport</span></a><br>
       <a href='roundtoseattle.php' class="btn btn-default btn-md" style='width: 310px;'><span class="network-name">Round Trip (Travel To Seattle)</span></a><br>
       <a href='roundfromseattle.php' class="btn btn-default btn-md" style='width: 310px;'><span class="network-name">Round Trip (Travel From Seattle)</span></a><br>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

     <section id="testimonials" class="container content-section text-center">
        <div class="row">

                <h2>Testimonials</h2>

                    <div class="table-responsive">
                      <table width='200%'>
                        <tr>
                            <?php
                                // Create connection
                                $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
                                // Check connection
                                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                                }

                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM testimonials";
                                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                                    // output data of each row
                                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                        echo "<td valign='top'>
                                <blockquote>
                                    <p class='clients-words'>".$row['testimonial']."</p>
                                    <span class='clients-name text-primary'>— ".$row['name']."</span>
                                </blockquote>
                            </td>";
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    echo "0 results";
                                }
                                $conn->close();
                            ?>




                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>


        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Contact Section -->
    <section id="contact" class="container content-section text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                <p>Call Us: (206) 412-9353 </p>
                <p>Email Us: <a href="mailto:info@awseattle.com">info@awseattle.com</a>
                </p>
                <ul class="list-inline banner-social-buttons">
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Twitter</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Facebook</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Google+</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container text-center">
            <p>Copyright &copy; AW Seattle 2014</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Maps API Key - Use your own API key to enable the map feature. More information on the Google Maps API can be found at https://developers.google.com/maps/ -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCRngKslUGJTlibkQ3FkfTxj3Xss1UlZDA&sensor=false"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/grayscale.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Any advice is appreciated. Not sure what to do ) :

Comment: Can you specify which versions of IE have the problem you're describing? Also, simply including the ehader code isn't going to help with anything. You need to include the code that's *actually having the problem*. Simply linking to your site is not sufficient, as that code can (and in your case likely will) change at some point, rendering this question and any answers it receives obsolete for future visitors.

Comment: Added additional code. As for version I am not sure. I am not the one viewing it, its a client.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

Comment: I looked, thats why I am here

Comment: So then ask the client which version of IE they're using....

Comment: I tried that they are clueless on how to use a pc but said its not important because it needs to work for all versions

Comment: You're unnecessarily including the HTML5shiv/shim twice.

Comment: Looks like you included some example code without changing it to use real values, e.g. `http://externalcdn.com/respond-proxy.html`

Comment: Work for all versions would mean you'd have to make it work going all the way back to the earliest versions of IE, and I guarnatee that's what they're thinking in their minds. You need to iterate the importance of targeted versioning to your clients, and explain the amount of extra effort you have to do as you go back further and further on version support. Walk them through how to find their version of IE if you have to. Sometimes you have to do the extra lifting to get the answers you need. Get creative.